# como hago si quiero obtener una url de de una web que no es mia pero no tiene id de llamada

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div id="refer_tab" style="display: block;" align="center" class="page_tabs"><p class="bold">bienvenidos</p><p>la tabla.</p><div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box table_header_background br_5_5">
     <div class="center" style="margin:auto;">cambios</div></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_container effect2"><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left "> ver </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"> 50% </div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left"> cambio / ver</div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"> 0.40%  mayor</div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left"> entrada </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"> 25%  </div></div></div></div><p class="bold">donde estas tu <a href="#" class="lottery_link"> ticket</a> and <a href="#" class="rewards_link"><span class="ref_rp_amount">0</span> RECLAMO</a> los cambios echos son realizado</p><div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="reward_table_box green_prize_rank br_5_5 bold" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f3cd00; font-weight: bold;"> URL</div><div class="reward_table_box br_0_0_5_5 font_bold" style="border-top:none;"><input type="text" size="25" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" value="i need this web" onclick="this.select();"></div></div></div><div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box table_header_background br_5_5"> <div class="center" style="margin:auto;">BANNERS</div></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_container effect2"><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left "> 728 x 90 </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_input reward_table_box_right"> <input type="text" size="40" style="text-align:center;" value="https://sin impotancia" onclick="this.select();"> </div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left"> 468 x 60 </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_input reward_table_box_right"> <input type="text" size="40" style="text-align:center;" value="sin impotancia" onclick="this.select();"> </div></div></div></div> <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="reward_table_box green_prize_rank br_5_5 bold" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f3cd00; font-weight: bold;">FORO </div><div class="reward_table_box br_0_0_5_5 font_bold" style="border-top:none;"> <input type="text" size="40" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" value="sin importancia" onclick="this.select();"> </div></div></div><p>base</p><p>Cambios.</p><p>estadistica.</p><div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="reward_table_box gold br_5_5 bold" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f3cd00; font-weight: bold;">TOTAL</div><div class="reward_table_box br_0_0_5_5 font_bold" style="border-top:none;">0</div></div></div><div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box table_header_background br_5_5"> <div class="center" style="margin:auto;">estados</div></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_container effect2"><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left " title="Total commissions made"> TOTAL </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right">0.00000000</div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left " title="Commissions made since last payout cycle"> RECENiente </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left" title="Commissions made from your referred users playing MULTIPLY BTC"> mayor </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right">0.00000000</div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left" title="Commissions made on daily interest paid to your referred users"> ver </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right">0.00000000</div></div></div></div> <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box table_header_background br_5_5"> <div class="center" style="margin:auto;">SEGUIR</div></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_container effect2"><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left " title="Total amount shared with referrals"> TOTAL </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"><span id="share_given">0.00000000</span></div><div class="large-12 small-12 columns center" style="height:10px;"> </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_left " title="Amount shared with referrals since last payout cycle"> RECENT </div><div class="large-6 small-12 columns center reward_table_box reward_table_box_right"><span id="recent_share_given"></span></div></div></div></div> <span class="bold">SEGUIR COMO </span><br><br>Usado.<br><br><div class="center bold" style="padding-bottom:10px;">MONTO</div><div style="width:250px;display:table;margin:0 auto;"><input type="text" name="stake" id="share_amount" value="0.00000001" style="text-align:center;"></div><div class="center"><input type="checkbox" id="equal_share" name="equal_share" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox"></span> <small>seguir</small><br><input type="checkbox" id="weighted_share" name="weighted_share" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox"></span> <small>Sactividad</small><br><input type="checkbox" id="last_payout_share" name="last_payout_share" checked="checked" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> <small>seguir</small></div><p><button type="submit" id="share_button" class="new_button_style profile_page_button_style" style="margin:auto;">SHARE!</button></p><p><small>ver</small></p><p class="bold"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-reveal-id="myModal4" style="color:#fff;"><button class="new_button_style deposit_withdraw_button_style center" style="margin:auto; width:300px;">AVANZADO</button></a></p><div class="center bold" style="padding-bottom:10px;" id="detailed_ref_stats">detalle actividad </div><p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowAdvancedStats(10)">10 DAYS</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowAdvancedStats(20)">20 DAYS</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowAdvancedStats(30)">30 DAYS</a></p><table id="detailed_ref_stats_table" style="display:none;"><tbody><tr><td class="bold">DATE</td><td class="bold">VISITS</td><td class="bold">SIGNUPS</td><td class="bold">convercion</td></tr></tbody></table><p class="bold">contador</p><div class="payout_time_remaining hasCountdown"><span class="countdown_row countdown_show4"><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">4</span><br>Days</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">21</span><br>Hours</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">16</span><br>Minutes</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">24</span><br>Seconds</span></span></div><p class="bold">AUTO-SHARE</p><small>(Set auto-share to 0 to disable it)</small><p>uso automatico.</p><p class="bold">Pporcentaje</p><p style="width:75px;"><input type="text" id="as_percent" value="0" style="text-align:center;"></p><div class="center"><input type="checkbox" id="as_equal_share" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox"></span> <small>seguir </small><br> <input type="checkbox" id="as_weighted_share" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox"></span> <small>seguir actividad</small><br> <input type="checkbox" id="as_last_payout_share" checked="checked" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> <small>actividad</small></div><p id="as_error" class="red bold" style="display:none;"></p><p id="as_success" class="green bold" style="display:none;"></p><p><button type="submit" value="" id="as_button" class="new_button_style profile_page_button_style" style="margin:auto; width:auto;">SET AUTO-SHARE</button></p><p class="bold">tu</p><table id="referral_list_table"><tbody><tr><td class="bold" rowspan="2">DIRECCION</td><td class="bold" colspan="2">COMMISSIONS</td><td class="bold" colspan="2">SEGUIR</td></tr><tr><td class="bold">TOTAL</td><td class="bold" title="COMMISSIONS">RECINTE</td><td class="bold" title="Total received received from you">TOTAL</td><td class="bold" title="received received from you since last payout cycle">RECIENTE</td></tr></tbody></table> <input type="hidden" id="referrals_shown" value="10"> <p id="show_more_refs_options"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowMoreRefs(10)" id="show_10_more_refs">ULTIMO 10</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowMoreRefs(9999999)" id="show_all_refs">VER TODO</a> </p></div>
```

bienvenidos

la tabla.

cambios ver  50%   cambio / ver 0.40%  mayor  entrada  25%  donde estas tu  ticket and 0 RECLAMO los cambios echos son realizado URL BANNERS 728 x 90     468 x 60    FORO

base

Cambios.

estadistica.

TOTAL0 estados TOTAL 0.00000000  RECENiente   mayor 0.00000000  ver 0.00000000  SEGUIR TOTAL 0.00000000  RECENT  SEGUIR COMO 
Usado.
MONTO seguir
 Sactividad
 seguir

SHARE!

ver

AVANZADOdetalle actividad

10 DAYS - 20 DAYS - 30 DAYS

DATEVISITSSIGNUPSconvercioncontador4
Days21
Hours16
Minutes24
SecondsAUTO-SHARE(Set auto-share to 0 to disable it)

uso automatico.

Pporcentaje seguir 
  seguir actividad
  actividad

SET AUTO-SHARE

tuDIRECCIONCOMMISSIONSSEGUIRTOTALRECINTETOTALRECIENTE   ULTIMO 10 - VER TODO

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita serios cambios y mejoras para siquiera entender lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: explica mejor que sucede, que tenes que hacer y que no te sale.

Comment: Trata de explicar mejor tu inconveniente, no peges directamente la tabla, puedes poner el código en su lugar; además lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: disculpen no sabia como usar la pagina ahora si hice los cambio no por completo pero ya esta mejor planteada la pregunta

Comment: @omar, necesitamos mas detalles. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta, agregar un "escenario", el resultado esperado y el código que has intentado.

Comment: @omar has lo que dice Ramiro, explicate

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;"><div class="small-12 large-centered small-centered columns change_size_css large-12"><div class="reward_table_box green_prize_rank br_5_5 bold" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f3cd00; font-weight: bold;">URL</div><div class="reward_table_box br_0_0_5_5 font_bold" style="border-top:none;"><input type="text" size="25" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;" value="Esta url " onclick="this.select();"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: No pongas mas codigo [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/417610/edit) tu pregunta y pon las aclaraciones de los comentarios. Te sugiero eliminar esto ya que esta seccion solo es para respuestas